# Why VSCode cannot locate playsound module or pydub module even after installing?

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code

Firstly, I am a newbie to python programming.

I am having a problem with the Playsound module and when searching for alternatives, I encountered the same problem with Pydub module also.

I have tried to install the Playsound module using both:

`pip install playsound`

and

`pip3 install playsound`

and these attempts were successful according to terminal.

but VSCode continues to show the folllowing error:

```
     No module named 'playsound'
       File "C:\Users\achin\OneDrive\Documents\QUIZZO\test.py", line 23, in <module>
         from playsound import playsound
```

All goes same for Pydub also.

Here is my code which I am using in VSCode for testing playsound:

```
from playsound import playsound
playsound('sample.mp3')
print('done playing')
```

Please Help.

As I am asking a question first time, some details might be missing, so please feel free to ask.

Thanks.